# Passing JSON Object to Rythm template

Tags: java, template-engine, rythm

I have some [Rythm](http://rythmengine.org/) templates registry and need to develop code that will render selected by client template (e.g. client will call my code by http and provide template name and parameters).
Due to call is performed by http - on my end I will have client-provided params as JSON (I even have not classes that represent user input), maybe parsed to `map of maps of maps...`. And It turn out that It's not handy to use such structure in template: all I can do is to use `Map::get(key)` method and only with 1 level nesting:

Next template get error due to `param.get("person")` is supposed as `Object` and have not `get(key)` method:

```
@args Map<String, Object> param
Hello @param.get("person").get("firstName").capFirst()!
```

I remember that some template engines support map-as-object syntax, e.g. pass `map of maps of ... of objects` to template and access it in template as POJO (or like accessing JSON object's field in JS), for exapmle:

```
@args Map param
Hello @param.person.firstName.capFirst()!
```

Is it possible with Rythm?

Or maybe there is another convinient way to solve such problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [dynamic evaluation](http://rythmengine.org/doc/template_guide.md#h4_0) by putting a `@` at the end of the expression:

```
@args com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject param
Hello @param.person.firstName.capFirst()@!
```

See http://fiddle.rythmengine.org/#/editor/ed3855c628144af287571cdf9857bcaa